# Gridmix fail all job

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to run Gridmix on Hadoop (2.6.1)

I was able to run a map reduce job on yarn and to run Rumen to extract a trace to simulate however I am not able to make the final step and run gridmix.

If I inspect the log I found an error:

```
{"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.TaskAttemptUnsuccessfulCompletion"

{"taskid":"task_1449829849459_0042_m_000000","taskType":"MAP","attemptId":"attempt_1449829849459_0042_m_000000_0","finishTime":1449841158377,"hostname":"simo","port":56154,"rackname":"/default-rack","status":"FAILED",

"error":"Error: 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
  org.apache.hadoop.tools.rumen.ResourceUsageMetrics
  \n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  \n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  \n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  \n\tat java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  \n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)\n\tat     sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  \n\tat java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  \n\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
  \n\tat java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2595)
  \n\tat java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2895)
  \n\tat java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2066)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:66)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.getSplitDetails(MapTask.java:372)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:751)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
  \n\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  \n\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
  \n\tat rg.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1656)
  \n\tat org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
\n",
"counters":
  {"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JhCounters":
    {"name":"COUNTERS",
     "groups":
        [{"name":"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter",
          "displayName":"Map-Reduce Framework",
          "counts":[{"name":"CPU_MILLISECONDS","displayName":"CPU time spent (ms)","value":0},
                    {"name":"PHYSICAL_MEMORY_BYTES","displayName":"Physical memory (bytes) snapshot","value":0},{"name":"VIRTUAL_MEMORY_BYTES","displayName":"Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot","value":0}]}]}},"clockSplits":[286,287,287,287,287,287,286,287,287,287,287,287],"cpuUsages":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"vMemKbytes":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"physMemKbytes":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}}}
```

This error seems very strange to me, and I don't quite grasp it.

I run gridmix by command line with:

`bin/hadoop jar share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-gridmix-2.6.1.jar iopath trace.json`

and `bin/hadoop classpath` give me:

```
$ bin/hadoop classpath
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/conf:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/common/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/hdfs:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/yarn/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/: <- here is hadoop-rumen-2.6.1.jar
/home/simo/hadoop-2.6.1/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/lib/:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar:
HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

which should include the file of rumen.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is coming from the task, not the command that started the gridmix run. As such, the hadoop classpath is not really the cause of this issue. You'd need to get the rumen jar onto your **task** classpath.

If you have administrative privileges of your cluster, you could add the rumen jar (and its dependencies) to the cluster install and make sure yarn.application.classpath picks it up.

Alternately you could provide it as a libjar so that it can get sent to the cluster with your job. You'll need to make sure all its necessary dependencies are included in the task classpath too.